# How to install Ubuntu 14.10 on a new Lenovo Ideapad g50-70

Tags: ubuntu, boot, usb, lenovo-laptop

I’m trying to install Ubuntu 14.10 (64 bit) on my new Lenovo Ideapad, but I can’t seem to boot from CD or USB.

I have disabled secure boot and fast boot in BIOS, boot mode: legacy (not UEFI).

I created a USB installer from USB-creator, but when I restart with USB, I just get a black screen with “Lenovo.” The same happens with the DVD.

Perhaps I need a special format while creating USB installer?

Or maybe try to do it with [UNetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net)?

Answer (score 4):

This new UEFI boot scheme is very confusing, I know. Fortunately with the latest Lenovo laptops you don't need to disable secure boot, nor do you need to disable fastboot, nor do you need legacy mode. You don't need any of that. At least for Ubuntu 12 and up.

Please [put it back](https://askubuntu.com/a/228069).  :-)

And follow the instructions on the link provided.

The only thing that excellent answer does not address is how to get to the point of booting from USB stick, on your **Lenovo**. The trick (I happen to discover this all by myself, simply by noticing an option not available in other instructions sets):

**[Shift]+Restart > Use USB Devices > USB Stick**

Comment: This saved me at least an hour.  My new laptop was preinstalled with windows 8.1.  I held shift while clicking restart, but there wasn't any indication that anything had changed.  However, on restart, a windows 8 looking boot screen came up and let me choose my boot option.

Answer (score 1):

I would say that there is not the best choice of USBCreator to make bootable USB-flash drive (sounds strange isn't it?).
Much more better way through command line:

> sudo dd if='ubuntu-14.10-desktop-amd64.iso' of=/dev/sdb bs=16M

Where `if` is input file. `of` is destination file. `bs` - read up to BYTES bytes at a time.

**Note**: Be careful while specifying path the destination usb device. Check out your path to the USB drive using Gnome Disk Utility (Open terminal and type `gnome-disks`).

Answer (score 1):

Previous posts in this thread as well as official Lenovo instructions are useless & factually void. Reference: http://support.lenovo.com/us/en/documents/ht076906

To access the Boot Menu:

1. Open the Charm Bar by pressing Windows Key-C
2. Click on Settings
3. Click on Change PC Settings
4. Click on General
5. Scroll to the bottom and click on Advanced Startup -> Restart Now
6. Click on Use A Device
7. Click on Boot Menu

Truth:

1. Open the Charm Bar by pressing Windows Key-C
2. Click on Settings
3. Click on Change PC Settings
4. There is no "General" setting. Here we deviate from the Lenovo Lie: Click on "Update and Recovery"
5. Advanced Startup / Restart Now
6. Click "Troubleshoot"
7. Click "Advanced Options"
8. Click "UEFO Firmware Settings"
9. Click "Restart"

   > BIOS now accessed.
10. right-arrow over to "Boot"
11. "Boot Mode / UEFI" is highlighted. Press "Enter", down-arrow to change to "Legacy Support"; press "Enter"
12. down-arrow to highlight "Boot Priority / UEFI First"; press "Enter"; down-arrow to select "Legacy First"; press "Enter"
13. down-arrow to highlight "USB Boot"; make sure it is "Enabled"
14. right-arrow to "Exit"; select "Exit Saving Changes"; press "Enter"