# Can a 64-bit OS be loaded on a 64-bit processor when the EFI is 32-bit?

Tags: cpu, 64-bit, efi, chromebook

I'm struggling to get a [Chromebook loaded with a new OS](https://superuser.com/q/1035433/173513). The Chromebook is a [Toshiba CB35-B3330](http://us.toshiba.com/computers/laptops/chromebook/cb30-2/CB35-B3330), and it has a 64-bit [Intel Celeron N2840](http://ark.intel.com/products/82103/Intel-Celeron-Processor-N2840-1M-Cache-up-to-2_58-GHz). I'm struggling because I can't get any useful information on the reason for the failure (i.e., I'm told it fails, but there are no messages or log files detailing why it failed).

When I check the output of ***`crossystem`***, it reports X86 and not X86_64:

```
$ crossystem --all | egrep -i "(x86|64)"
arch                   = x86                            # Platform architecture
```

I'm guessing the EFI is following Chrome OS, meaning its 32-bit, too. I haven't really followed BIOS and EFI development in about 20 years, so I'm kind of uninformed when it comes to exact details of interactions and operations.

Can a 64-bit OS be loaded on a 64-bit processor when the firmware is 32-bit?

Comment: This is possible.  A lot of the new Intel Atom based tablets have the same limitation.  (Note that by possible I mean its possible to have a 32 bit EFI loading a 64 bit platform - I am not saying you can put a different OS on a Chromebook - I have not looked into this)

Comment: @Ramhound - Have a look at http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2252391 and https://blogs.intel.com/evangelists/2015/07/22/why-cheap-systems-run-32-bit-uefi-on-x64-systems/

Comment: Thanks @Ramhound. *"A 64-bit processor can run a 32-bit OS though..."* - I'm trying to use the full register set of x86_64. i386 has 8 registers, while x86_64 has 16 of them. Hence the reason I am trying to determine if its a valid configuration.

Comment: Thanks @davidgo. *"This is possible. Note that by possible I mean its possible to have a 32 bit EFI loading a 64 bit platform..."* - OK, thanks. Do you know how to check if its an available option on a particular machine (like a Toshiba Chromebook CB35-B3330), rather than in the general sense?

Comment: The ability to boot a 64-bit OS on a system with a 32-bit EFI depends on two things: the presence of a 64-bit CPU and boot loader features. It's not a feature of the firmware itself; instead, the 32-bit GRUB (or other boot loader) you launch must have the ability to launch a 64-bit kernel. This is equivalent to a 16-bit BIOS-mode GRUB launching a 32- or 64-bit kernel. Such cross-bit-depth booting is less well-supported in the EFI world than in the BIOS world. Personally, I don't recommend it if you can avoid it; it's much easier to boot a kernel of the EFI's native bit depth.

Comment: I gave the Toshiba Chromebook away and bought a Lenoveo Ideapad. I'm having similar problems. Here's some more information about 32-bit EFI... [How to install Ubuntu 14.10 on a new Lenovo Ideapad](http://superuser.com/q/852235), [Ubuntu/Debian on a Lenovo Ideapad 100s](http://askubuntu.com/q/684041) and [32-Bit UEFI Boot Support](http://askubuntu.com/q/392719).